# How can i catch error message from command line TCL

Tags: try-catch, tcl, message, qsub, vlsi

I'm writing script at tcl on ICC and trying to get error message while sending ran to sung-grid.

For example, I have the below line.

```
sh /usr/bin/xterm -e "cd DM ; mqsub -int -parallel 200 cal -cal -t 200 CAL_header | tee S.log ; touch .S_finished" &
```

since I don't have 200 free cpu, If i execute this command line at linux shell I'll get the below message:
"Your "qrsh" request could not be scheduled, try again later."

How can i catch this error message at ICC with & and the end of the command?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you are executing the shell command by means of using `exec` in tcl.

In that case, you could use `catch` statement to get identify the error message.

```
if { [catch {exec <your_shell_program_command_here>} result] } {
    puts "Following problem happened : $result"
    exit 1
}
```

**Syntax :**

```
catch script ?varName?
```

Quoting the below from the [man page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/catch.htm)

> If script raises an error, catch will return a non-zero integer value
>   corresponding to the exceptional return code returned by evaluation of
>   script. Tcl defines the normal return code from script evaluation to
>   be zero (0), or TCL_OK. Tcl also defines four exceptional return
>   codes: 1 (TCL_ERROR), 2 (TCL_RETURN), 3 (TCL_BREAK), and 4
>   (TCL_CONTINUE). Errors during evaluation of a script are indicated by
>   a return code of TCL_ERROR.

Comment: While trying to exec /usr/bin/xterm i get below message:
Error: /usr/bin/xterm: /usr/bin/xterm: cannot execute binary file

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean **Synopsys ICCompiler** by term ICC?

If there is any error regarding *queue* for launching the job for any EDA tool kindly prefer, the following way of launching.

```
{launch command for job (qsub *switches* ) } > & log &
```

this will eliminate the troubleshooting difficulties. 
Sorry for posting this question as answer but i am unable to comment

Comment: Yes you right.
I mean Synopsys ICCompiler.

What is "launch command"?
Can you write the full command established on my main message?

Comment: `qsub -P bnormal -l "project=msem,os_distribution=redhat,qsc=i,os_version=WS5.0,mem_free=8G" -v version_path=/remote/user/emll/tools/system//latest -o vnc_logs    -cwd -A long /remote/user/emll/tools/system/latest/bin/ss > & log &`
this is typical example of launch command

Comment: the `qsh` version must be set before launch of command. Since you tried to launch job with 200 free CPU and I cannot see they queue type. i suggest you to meet your local IT team and check about **"long" queue**.
Usually long queue is preferred for such type of jobs

Comment: i think term is altered by using `setenv term xterm`

or better write down the command in other file and source the file.
use **shebang** as header of file if needed for all environment settings i.e. `#!/usr/bin/****`